# Given an html paragraph and a link, is there a way to retrieve the text before and the text after the link inside the paragraph in Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib3

I am using urllib3 to get the html of some pages.

I want to retrieve the text from the paragraph where the link is, with the text before and after the link stored separately.

**For example:**

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('get', "https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/michael-novenche/")
body = r.data
soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'lxml')
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    if a.has_attr('href'):
        if (a['href'] == "http://web.archive.org/web/20040330161553/http://newyork.local.ie/content/31666.shtml/albany/news/newsletters/general"):
            link_text = a
            link_para = a.find_parent("p")
            print(link_text)
            print(link_para)
```

**Paragraph**

```
<p>The message quoted above about Michael Novenche, a two-year-old boy 
undergoing chemotherapy to treat a brain tumor, was real, but keeping up with 
all the changes in his condition proved a challenge.  The message quoted above 
stated that Michael had a large tumor in his brain, was operated upon to 
remove part of the tumor, and needed prayers to help him through chemotherapy 
to a full recovery.  An <nobr>October 2000</nobr> article in <a 
href="http://web.archive.org/web/20040330161553/http://newyork.local.ie/conten
t/31666.shtml/albany/news/newsletters/general" 
onmouseout="window.status='';return true" onmouseover="window.status='The
Local Albany Weekly';return true" target="_blank"><i>The Local Albany 
Weekly</i></a> didn’t mention anything about little Michael’s medical 
condition but said that his family was “in need of funds to help pay for the
 transportation to the hospital and other costs not covered by their 
insurance.”  A June 2000 message posted to the <a 
href="http://www.ecunet.org/whatisecupage.html" 
onmouseout="window.status='';return true" 
onmouseover="window.status='Ecunet';return true" target="_blank">Ecunet</a> 
mailing list indicated that Michael had just turned <nobr>3 years</nobr> old, 
mentioned that his tumor appeared to be shrinking, and provided a mailing 
address for him:</p>
```

**Link**

```
<a href="http://web.archive.org/web/20040330161553/http://newyork.local.ie/conten
t/31666.shtml/albany/news/newsletters/general"
onmouseout="window.status='';return true" onmouseover="window.status='The 
Local Albany Weekly';return true" target="_blank"><i>The Local Albany 
Weekly</i></a>
```

**Text to be retrieved (2 parts)**

```
The message quoted above about Michael Novenche, a two-year-old boy 
undergoing chemotherapy ... was operated upon to 
remove part of the tumor, and needed prayers to help him through chemotherapy 
to a full recovery.  An October 2000 article in
```

```
didn’t mention anything about little Michael’s medical 
condition but said that his family was ... turned 3 years old, 
mentioned that his tumor appeared to be shrinking, and provided a mailing 
address for him:
```

I cant simply get_text() then use split as the link text might be repeated.

I thought I might just add a counter to see how many times the link text is repeated, use split(), then use a loop to get the parts I want.

I would appreciate a better, less messy method though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on @Andrej kesely's solution.

It deals with two problems:

1. That there is no text before/after the link
2. That the link isn't a direct child of the paragraph

Here it is *(as a function)*:

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

def get_info(page,link):
    r = http.request('get', page)
    body = r.data
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'lxml')
    a = soup.find('a', href=link)
    s, parts = '', []

    if a.parent.name=="p":
        for t in a.parent.contents:
            if t == a:
                parts += [s]
                s = ''
                continue
            s += str(t)
        parts += [s]
    else:
        prnt = a.find_parents("p")[0]
        for t in prnt.contents:
            if t == a or (str(a) in str(t)):
                parts+=[s]
                s=''
                continue
            s+=str(t)
        parts+=[s]

    try:
        text_before_link = BeautifulSoup(parts[0], 'lxml').body.text.strip()
    except AttributeError as error:
        text_before_link = ""

    try:
        text_after_link = BeautifulSoup(parts[1], 'lxml').body.text.strip()
    except AttributeError as error:
        text_after_link = ""

    return text_before_link, text_after_link
```

This assumes that there is no paragraph inside another paragraph.

If anyone has any ideas about scenarios where this fails, please feel free to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate `a` tag parent's content and compare if actual value is our `a` tag. If it is, we found one part and continue building another:

```
data = '''<p>The message quoted above about Michael Novenche, a two-year-old boy
undergoing chemotherapy to treat a brain tumor, was real, but keeping up with
all the changes in his condition proved a challenge.  The message quoted above
stated that Michael had a large tumor in his brain, was operated upon to
remove part of the tumor, and needed prayers to help him through chemotherapy
to a full recovery.  An <nobr>October 2000</nobr> article in <a
href="http://web.archive.org/web/20040330161553/http://newyork.local.ie/content/31666.shtml/albany/news/newsletters/general"
onmouseout="window.status='';return true" onmouseover="window.status='The
Local Albany Weekly';return true" target="_blank"><i>The Local Albany
Weekly</i></a> didn’t mention anything about little Michael’s medical
condition but said that his family was “in need of funds to help pay for the
 transportation to the hospital and other costs not covered by their
insurance.”  A June 2000 message posted to the <a
href="http://www.ecunet.org/whatisecupage.html"
onmouseout="window.status='';return true"
onmouseover="window.status='Ecunet';return true" target="_blank">Ecunet</a>
mailing list indicated that Michael had just turned <nobr>3 years</nobr> old,
mentioned that his tumor appeared to be shrinking, and provided a mailing
address for him:</p>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

link_url='http://web.archive.org/web/20040330161553/http://newyork.local.ie/content/31666.shtml/albany/news/newsletters/general'
a = soup.find('a', href=link_url)

s, parts = '', []
for t in a.parent.contents:
    if t == a:
        parts += [s]
        s = ''
        continue
    s += str(t)
parts += [s]

for part in parts:
    print(BeautifulSoup(part, 'lxml').body.text.strip())
    print('*' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
The message quoted above about Michael Novenche, a two-year-old boy
undergoing chemotherapy to treat a brain tumor, was real, but keeping up with
all the changes in his condition proved a challenge.  The message quoted above
stated that Michael had a large tumor in his brain, was operated upon to
remove part of the tumor, and needed prayers to help him through chemotherapy
to a full recovery.  An October 2000 article in
********************************************************************************
didn’t mention anything about little Michael’s medical
condition but said that his family was “in need of funds to help pay for the
 transportation to the hospital and other costs not covered by their
insurance.”  A June 2000 message posted to the Ecunet
mailing list indicated that Michael had just turned 3 years old,
mentioned that his tumor appeared to be shrinking, and provided a mailing
address for him:
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: This works for some pages. In other pages, ```a``` isnt a first child of the paragraph (ie ```<p><nobr><a></a></nobr></p>```), any idea how to deal with this? Also, a ```try: except AttributeError:``` block is needed before parsing the parts using bs4 in case there is no text before/after the link (eg:: ```word words link:```)

Comment: @MohamadMoustafa Can you provide example of such page?

Comment: ```https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/rebuilding-iraq/``` first link in this article. I already figured a way to approach this (answer down below). It's a bit "hacky", but so far it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

can you clarify what you mean by:

> I cant simply get_text() then use split as the link text might be
>   repeated

When I run:

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import certifi

http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())

r = http.request('GET', "https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/michael-novenche/")
body = r.data
soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'lxml')
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    if a.has_attr('href'):
        if (a['href'] == "http://web.archive.org/web/20040330161553/http://newyork.local.ie/content/31666.shtml/albany/news/newsletters/general"):
            link_text = a
            link_para = a.find_parent("p")
            print(link_para.get_text())
```

I get:

> The message quoted above about Michael Novenche, a two-year-old boy undergoing chemotherapy to treat a brain tumor, was real, but keeping up with all the changes in his condition proved a challenge.  The message quoted above stated that Michael had a large tumor in his brain, was operated upon to remove part of the tumor, and needed prayers to help him through chemotherapy to a full recovery.  An October 2000 article in The Local Albany Weekly didn’t mention anything about little Michael’s medical condition but said that his family was “in need of funds to help pay for the transportation to the hospital and other costs not covered by their insurance.”  A June 2000 message posted to the Ecunet mailing list indicated that Michael had just turned 3 years old, mentioned that his tumor appeared to be shrinking, and provided a mailing address for him:

The text is being split by the 'The Local Albany Weekly' which is the name of the link.. so why not get the link name and split by that?

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())

r = http.request('GET', "https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/michael-novenche/")
body = r.data
soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'lxml')
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    if a.has_attr('href'):
        if (a['href'] == "http://web.archive.org/web/20040330161553/http://newyork.local.ie/content/31666.shtml/albany/news/newsletters/general"):
            link_text = a
            link_para = a.find_parent("p")
            the_link = link_para.find('a')
            #change the name of <i> to something unique
            the_link.string.replace_with('ooqieri')
            name_link = link_text.findAll('i')[0].get_text()
            full_text = link_para.get_text().split(name_link)
            print(full_text)
```

which gives:

> ['The message quoted above about Michael Novenche, a two-year-old boy undergoing chemotherapy to treat a brain tumor, was real, but keeping up with all the changes in his condition proved a challenge.  The message quoted above stated that Michael had a large tumor in his brain, was operated upon to remove part of the tumor, and needed prayers to help him through chemotherapy to a full recovery.  An October 2000 article in ', ' didn’t mention anything about little Michael’s medical condition but said that his family was “in need of funds to help pay for the transportation to the hospital and other costs not covered by their insurance.”  A June 2000 message posted to the Ecunet mailing list indicated that Michael had just turned 3 years old, mentioned that his tumor appeared to be shrinking, and provided a mailing address for him:']

Comment: Because some pages have other words inside the <a>. If those words appear again somewhere in the paragraph, it wont split into two parts but more.

Comment: Gotcha, you can just change the words inside the <a> to something you would absolutely never see so you can do a reliable split. I updated my code to reflect that!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with bs4 4.7.1. Use `:has` and an attribute = value selector to get the parent `p` tag then split it's html on the `a` tag html. Then re-parse with bs for `p` tags. This gets around the potentially repeated phrase problem. Only poses a problem if it is possible for the entire html of the `a` tag to appear repeated within the block which seems highly unlikely.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/michael-novenche/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
data = soup.select_one('p:has(>[href="http://web.archive.org/web/20040330161553/http://newyork.local.ie/content/31666.shtml/albany/news/newsletters/general"])').encode_contents().split(soup.select_one('[href="http://web.archive.org/web/20040330161553/http://newyork.local.ie/content/31666.shtml/albany/news/newsletters/general"]').encode_contents())
items = [bs(i, 'lxml').select_one('p').text for i in data]
print(items)
```

Comment: Is this what you intended?

Comment: I am getting ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode_contents``` after using your exact code.

Comment: I just ran it and it ran fine so not sure what the problem is for you. Are you using bs4 4.7.1?

Comment: I just installed an upgrade for bs4 and lxml. Now lxml (which I need for another package as well) is giving me errors :/

Comment: I can only suggest you research the errors. I use both and haven’t experienced any issues with upgrading I’m afraid.

Comment: I reinstalled my packages using conda and they work fine now.

Comment: And you are getting the expected result?

Comment: yes, but as Andrej's solution seems easier to edit for handling the two exceptions mentioned in my answer, I ended using that instead. Otherwise I wouldve used this as it looks "neater". Thank you.